# Dirac field operator act on the right side of Green function

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, fermions, greens-functions, propagator

On P&S's QFT book, chapter 9.5, the book discussed how to derive two point correlation function for dirac field using generating functional.

Start with $$
Z[\bar{\eta}, \eta]=\int \mathcal{D} \bar{\psi} \mathcal{D} \psi \exp \left[i \int d^4 x[\bar{\psi}(i \not \partial-m) \psi+\bar{\eta} \psi+\bar{\psi} \eta]\right] \tag{9.73}
$$
we can shift the field as:
$$\begin{aligned}\psi &\leadsto \psi-i \int d^4 y S_F(x-y) \eta(y)\\ \bar{\psi} &\leadsto \bar{\psi}-i \int d^4 y \bar{\eta}(y) S_F(x-y) \end{aligned}$$

I met following term in the derivation:
$$\int d^4 x d^4 y \bar{\eta}(y)S_F(x-y)(i\not\partial-m)\psi^{\prime}(x) $$

So how to handle this term? I know that $(i\not\partial-m)S_F(x-y)=i\delta^4(x-y)$, but this time the differential operator appear on the right side of $S_F(x-y)$.

In my attempt of derivation:

(1) Should I write them in components form? (i.e. $S_F(x-y)_{ab}$)

(2) If not, in the Integration by part, how do we handle $i\not\partial-m$? Since there is gamma matrices.

---

Another point is that I fail to shift the field by directly using $\psi^{\prime}\equiv \psi+(i\not\partial-m)^{-1}\eta$, I summarized this question in this [post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/737959/field-shift-in-generating-functional-for-the-dirac-field).

--

EDIT: $\stackrel{\star}{=}$ expansion in J.G.'s excellent answer!
$$\begin{aligned}&\int d^4y \overline{\eta(y)}S_F(x-y)(i\not\partial_x-m)\psi(x) \\
&=\text{Surface}-\int d^4y \overline{\eta(y)}(i\not\partial_x+m)S_F(x-y)\psi(x)\\
&=\int d^4y \overline{\eta(y)}(i\not\partial_y-m)S_F(x-y)\psi(x) \\
&=\int d^4y \overline{\eta(y)}(i\not\partial_y-m)S_F(y-x)\psi(x)\end{aligned}$$

Comment: General tip: Consider to only ask 1 question per post.

Comment: In your edit, what do you mean by $\psi'$? My answer's strategy was to replace $\overline{\eta}S_F\not\partial_x\psi$ [sic] with $-\overline{\eta}\not\partial_xS_F\psi$ by IBP, then with $\overline{\eta}\not\partial_yS_F\psi$ since $S_F$ is a function of $x-y$.

Comment: @J.G. Thanks! Sorry for the notation, my $\psi^{\prime}$ is same with your $\psi$! That's clear! So we don't need to consider the gamma matrix commutation problem in $\not\partial$ and $S_F$? I re-edit my post, sorry for confusion!

Comment: @J.G. Sorry for bothering, I don't totally understand the last step in my new EDIT! $S_F(x-y)=\int\frac{d^4 k}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{i(\not k+m)}{k^2-m^2+i\epsilon}e^{-ik(x-y)}$, why could $S_F(x-y)$ invariant under $x \leftrightarrow y$?

Answer (score 2):

(1) is overkill. Write the shift as $\psi\leadsto\psi+\delta\psi$ etc. Since the operators $\delta,\,i\not\partial-m$ commute and $(i\not\partial-m)\delta\psi(x)=\eta(x)$,$$\begin{align}\delta\left(\overline{\psi}(x)(i\not\partial-m)\psi(x)\right)&=\overline{\psi}(x)(i\not\partial-m)\delta\psi(x)+\delta\overline{\psi}(x)(i\not\partial-m)\psi(x)\\&=\overline{\psi}(x)\eta(x)-i\int d^4y\overline{\eta}(y)S_F(x-y)(i\not\partial-m)\psi(x)\\&\stackrel{\star}{=}\overline{\psi}(x)\eta(x)-i\int d^4y\overline{\eta}(y)(i\not\partial-m)S_F(x-y)\psi(x)\\&=\overline{\psi}(x)\eta(x)+\overline{\eta}(x)\psi(x),\end{align}$$where $\stackrel{\star}{=}$ assumes integration by parts with a vanishing surface term. Note for (2) that $S_F(x-y)$ is invariant under $x\leftrightarrow y$, so $\not\partial_yS_F=-\not\partial_xS_F$, which cancels IBP's usual sign change. (This also addresses [another question of yours](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4586826).) Hence$$Z=\int\mathcal{D}\overline{\psi}\mathcal{D}\psi\exp\left[i\int d^4x[f+\delta f]\right],\,f:=\overline{\psi}(x)(i\not\partial-m)\psi(x).$$

Comment: Excellent answer! Thank you very much! May I ask additional two questions? (1) Could you please check my EDIT in my post about your star formula? This also require $\partial_y \overline{\eta(y)}=0$ after the IBP, so is this true? (2) Since your derivation don't write out the spinor components explicitly, and $\gamma^{\mu}$ in $\not\partial$ may not commute with $S_F(x-y)$! (in the IBP, we exchange their order)  So can we ensure us this? Thanks!

Comment: If you have time, could you please see my another post(link) above EDIT! That's about spinor field replacement! But any way, you already helped me a lot, I am really appreciate your help!

Comment: Sorry, I need un-accept your  answer! Since I don’t understand the first step before IBP. So in the integration of $d^4 y$, how can we handle $\partial_x$? Thanks!